# Spring Groovy Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, groovy

I am a newbie to `Spring` and `Groovy` integration.

I have some strange requirement.  Please help in achieving it.

I have Groovy scripts in a database and in a flow I want to get a script from the database and execute the script.
But the problem here is I want the Spring container inside that script and I want to call any beans of Spring container from Groovy script.
Now the problem is how to specify the Spring container to scan the Groovy scripts in database. Also Groovy scripts get added and removed from the database.  I also don't want to restart the application when a new script is added.

Comment: Why is this tagged grails?

Comment: @tim_yates my mistake

Comment: The question about the Spring container is confusing.  Is this a Spring app whose context you want available in the script or do you want a new context that is only visible from within the script?

Comment: @JohnScattergood i want context inside script.Problem for me was i need to hardcode the beans inside the xml file and groovy scripts should be in classpath.What i just need is get the script from database and that script should contain context.what i am thinking is to send instance of applicationcontext to script and it should contain all beans.